# Extremely slow groupby and join Linq query

Tags: linq, razor-pages, .net-7.0

I have a query where I want a left join on 3 tables then groupby and perform some logic. However, the query is super slow. I think the `FirstOrDefault()` could be the culprit here but cant work out why it is so slow. Can anybody spot where I may be going wrong here, and suggest ways to improve the performance of the query :)

```cs
var result =
    from admins in _db.ContactAdmins
    where admins.SupervisorId == assignmentNumber
    from contact in _db.ContactShifts.Where(x => admins.AssignmentNumber == x.AssignmentNumber).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from esr in _db.VEsrRecords.Where(x => admins.AssignmentNumber == x.AssignmentNumber).DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new
    {
        esr,
        contact
    }
    by new
    {
        AssignmentNumber = esr.AssignmentNumber,
        Forename = esr.FirstName,
        Surname = esr.LastName,
        Email = esr.EmailAddress,
        Role = esr.PositionName,
    }
    into dashboard
    select new
    {
        Id = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.IsActive).Select(x => x.contact.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
        AssignmentNumber = dashboard.Key.AssignmentNumber,
        Forename = dashboard.Key.Forename,
        Surname = dashboard.Key.Surname,
        Email = dashboard.Key.Email,
        Role = dashboard.Key.Role,
        ContactCount = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.ContactShiftStart.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Sum(x => x.contact.ContactCount),
        IsComplete = dashboard.OrderByDescending(x => x.contact.Id).Where(x => x.contact.IsComplete == true).Select(x => x.contact.IsComplete).FirstOrDefault(),
        IsScheduled = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.IsScheduled == true).Select(x => x.contact.IsScheduled).FirstOrDefault(),
        IsStarted = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.IsStarted == true).Select(x => x.contact.IsStarted).FirstOrDefault(),
        IsActive = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.IsActive == true).Select(x => x.contact.IsActive).FirstOrDefault(),
        SentForReview = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.IsActive == true).Select(x => x.contact.HasLeadSentForReview).FirstOrDefault(),
        ClinicianSignOff = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.IsActive == true).Select(x => x.contact.HasClinicianSignedOff).FirstOrDefault(),
        LatestContact = dashboard.OrderByDescending(x => x.contact.Id).Where(x => x.contact.IsComplete == true).Select(x => x.contact.ContactShiftStart).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
        ScheduledContact = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.IsActive).Select(x => x.contact.ContactShiftStart).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
        Guid = dashboard.Where(x => x.contact.IsActive == true).Select(x => x.contact.GuidId).FirstOrDefault()
    };

return new JsonResult(result);
```

Comment: Have you tried writing your own SQL and executing that? If so, and it performs acceptably, why not use that instead?

Comment: Main problem here us grouping, which is not needed for such query. Which EF Core version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This query should be written without grouping. `GroupBy` has only one effective usage - calculate aggregates. In your cse, you are trying to retrieve details from the group.
If you are using EF Core 7 or higher, you can use GroupJoin.

```cs
var thisYearStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
var nextYearStart = thisYearStart.AddYears(1);

var result =
    from admins in _db.ContactAdmins
    where admins.SupervisorId == assignmentNumber
    join esr in _db.VEsrRecords on admins.AssignmentNumber equals esr.AssignmentNumber
    join contact in _db.ContactShifts on admins.AssignmentNumber equals contact.AssignmentNumber into contactGroup
    from activeContact in contactGroup.Where(x => x.IsActive)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        Id = activeContact.Id,
        AssignmentNumber = esr.AssignmentNumber,
        Forename = esr.Forename,
        Surname = esr.Surname,
        Email = esr.Email,
        Role = esr.Role,
        ContactCount = contactGroup.Where(x => x.ContactShiftStart.Value >= thisYearStart && x.ContactShiftStart.Value < nextYearStart).Sum(x => x.ContactCount),
        IsComplete = contactGroup.Any(x => x.IsComplete),
        IsScheduled = contactGroup.Any(x => x.IsScheduled),
        IsStarted = contactGroup.Any(x => x.IsStarted),
        IsActive = activeContact != null,
        SentForReview = contactGroup.Any(x => x.IsActive && x.HasLeadSentForReview),
        ClinicianSignOff = contactGroup.Any(x => x.IsActive && x.HasClinicianSignedOff),
        LatestContact = contactGroup.Where(x => x.IsComplete).Max(x => x.ContactShiftStart),
        ScheduledContact = contactGroup.Where(x => x.IsActive).Min(x => x.ContactShiftStart),
        Guid = activeContact.GuidId
    };

return new JsonResult(result);
```

This is not final and best variant, but you should learn from this query haow to retrieve data effectively. Especially look at `activeContact`, probably you can reus it for other columns calculation.
Also note that instead `x.ContactShiftStart.Value.Year` filtering i have used date rabge filter, it is more effective if you have indexe on `ContactShiftStart` column.